# Modify Model in MVC 5 EF5 after find function

Tags: c#, model, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5

I need after loading the data from a model, automatically insert an information on a property of this type which do not come from the DB.

Exemple:

```
namespace project.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    public partial class MessageSource
    {
        public MessageSource()
        {
            this.messages = new HashSet<Message>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }

        public string message_translation { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Message> messages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

id, category and message are DB table properties, message_translation no, after loading this model, always I will need to put automatically information in message_translation. How?

Comment: Where do you get the data to set `message_translation`?

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
public partial class MessageSource
{
    public MessageSource()
    {
        this.messages = new HashSet<Message>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }

    public string message_translation { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Message> messages { get; set; }

    public string getTranslate()
    {
        if(message_translation == null)
        {
            Message msg = messages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.language.Equals(Translate.Instance.getLanguage()));

            if(msg != null)
            {
                message_translation = msg.translation;
            }
            else
            {
                message_translation = String.Empty;
            }
        }

        return message_translation;
    }
}
```

works good

Comment: good solution.. since it works for you , why don't mark your answer as the accepted answer , so others can benefit from it

Comment: i will propose another answer inspired by your answer see below

Answer (score 0):

```
messageSource m = new messageSource();
var m2 = // query your db using sql or entity framework
```

Then

```
m.id= m2.id;
m.category= m.category;
m.message= m2.message
m.message_translation= "vvvvvvv whatever"//do add thing here
m.messages = m2.messages;
```

Edit:

**Another solution**

```
Public class translation {
public int Id { get; set;}
public string language { get; set;}
public string text { get; set;}
}
```

Then you add in your messageSource model the following after removing message_translation

```
Public Icollection<translation> transMsg { get; set;}
```

Now suppose you have a msg that is translated into 13 languages; then the `ICollection<transMsg>` will have 13 item, and we need only the chinese translation

Do as follow:
First get your message

```
var myMsg = dbContext.messageSources.Where(m=>m.id== 6).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will not load any translation bec. We didnt use `Include()` , i.e. lazy loading

However, when we want the translation we pull it via another Linq query as follow:

```
var myMsgTranslation = myMsg.transMsgs.Where(t=>t.lang == "chinese").FirstOrDefault();
```

Or  you load all the translations as follow

```
    var myMsg = dbContext.messageSources.Where(m=>m.id== 6).Include(m=>m.msgTrans).FirstOrDefault();
```

And in yor View page u pull the default language as follow

```
@html.textBoxFor(model=>model.msgTrans.Where(t=>t.lang == "chinese"))
```

Desclaimer: not tested

Hope that help

Comment: I need get this info insite the model... =/

Comment: A model is just a model, you need to understand the concept of models!!! Are you willing to put same translation for each record in database??

Comment: I understand this concept, but I wonder if there is a way to do this automatically no need to do the same code throughout the system to get the translation. SOmething like this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2011 and I NEED to put translation for each record in DB

Comment: You are not clear in your requirement.  So you will save translation in db? In different table?? If that is the case, then you create another model especially for translation, and you refrence it from your messageSource model...

Comment: I will do it, but, a message can have many translations in different languages, I need get only active language translation

Comment: if I do this you suggest, I will have a list of messages in the Message property? I need only one, that would be the language active in the system at the moment.

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for AoP. Have you tried PostSharp?

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MessageSource
{
private string _defaultLanguage;
public MessageSource(string defaultLang)
{
    this.messages = new HashSet<Message>();
    this._defaultLanguage = defaultLanguage ;
}

public int id { get; set; }
public string category { get; set; }
public string message { get; set; }

public string message_translation { get; 
set{ value = getTranslation(_defaultLnag); }

public virtual ICollection<Message> messages { get; set; }

public string getTranslate(string lang)
{

         var Translation = dbcontext.messages.Where(m=> m.Id == this.Id).FirstOrDefault().Translation.Where(t=>t.lang == lang).FirstOrDefault();


    return Translation;
 }
}
```

this solution assume that you are saving the translations in a separate table linked to the messages tables